# How can my wife use my iPod touch with her Facebook account?

Tags: ipod-touch, facebook

My wife ruined her 4<sup>th</sup>-generation iPod touch in the pouring rain at Farm Aid this weekend. I have a 3<sup>rd</sup>-generation iPod touch that I don't use often because I have an iPhone.

How can I get her Facebook account to work on that iPod and remove my account? I can use my account on my iPhone instead.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the iOS levels, you might have to do the following:

1. Sign out of Facebook / remove the account from the settings app
2. Sign out of the Facebook app

At that point, your wife's account would be free to sign in to either the Facebook app or the system wide Facebook account slot for general sharing.